# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n+1} = 0.66215 + \frac{1}{2}\log(\infty)^{3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Just finished *Euler: The Master of us All*. A good fraction of the book is dedicated to explaining in why certain divergent series were useful in proving Euler's theorems, but this one is never explained:
\begin{align}
1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} + \cdots = 0.66215 + \frac{1}{2}\log(\infty)^{3}
\end{align}
I'm baffled by this expression. I'm ok with $\infty = \infty$, but why would it be reasonable to express it in this fashion, and what is the utility?

Comment: That expression doesn't mean anything at all.

Comment: I suspect this is related to the sloppy notation of things like the $\frac{-1}{12}=\zeta(-1)=1+2+3+4+\cdots$

Comment: Are you sure of the power of $\log$?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Does it matter at all??

Comment: @Timbuc: off course it matters!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Really? So you're attaching some definite meaning to $\;\log(\infty)\;$ and thus to its powers?

Comment: @Timbuc : Listen carefully: yes. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Timbuc : I say that without knowing what the definite meaning is, but given that Euler wrote this, it is highly probable that there is one, even if Euler himself could not define it precisely.  If a quite different person from Euler had written it, then I would not find it implausible that it's nonsense. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The $^3$ perhaps is a footnote?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : I don't think that sort of thing is sloppy notation; it's just that that notation doesn't explain the meaning. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Listen carefully: I did'nt ask whether Euler thought of that as having a definite meaning or not, but whether Mhenni himself *gives* some definite meaning to that so thatt its powers matter. If you, or anyone else, don't know what Euler meant then I can't understand how that power may be important. Relying on authority, even Euler, for this issomething I can't do.

Comment: @Timbuc : I would approach this not by refusing to think about it until after I knew the meaning, but by wondering if I could find out the meaning.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I've no doubt you can find the meaning of the expression, and I think it'd be something interesting. My point to Mhenni though is that if someone *doesn't know* what the meaning is then why to worry about the third or whatever power of that expression? What if it was two, four or $\;26\;$ ? This can only mean something, perhaps, if we know what the expression is. Mhenni even wrote "of course it matters!"...but why?! If you can't tell the meaning of the expression how can you tell this?

Comment: The ${}^3$ appears to be a footnote (rather poor style!); see the image in [user157227's answer below](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1091424/194204) with a ${}^4$ footnote shortly thereafter.

Comment: @aes I tried following the footnote, but it's not the right page. I must have a different edition of Euler's book or something. (The page I _did_ end up on, by the way, had the phrase "If we divide the equation by $x^\infty$"!)

Comment: Is there no reference to Euler's original article?

Comment: [Full page](http://i.imgur.com/3QDRIHT.jpg). Try seeing if you can follow the footnote.

Comment: The formula and its evaluation is an error in the manuscript of the book of the AMS; so no need to try to discover a hidden concept behind it; instead Euler had a correct solution in the same way like the correct answers here at your question reproduce it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For
$$
\left(\sum_{n=0}^{500} \frac 1 {2n+1}\right) - \frac 1 2\log(2\cdot500+1) = \left(\sum_{\text{odd }n\,\le\,1001} \frac 1 n\right) - \frac 1 2\log(1001) 
$$
I get $0.6368\ldots$.  Might Euler have had in mind some sort of limit as the number in place of $500$ grows?

Comment: This sounds much likely, since we have $$ \sum_{k : \text{odd } \leq n} \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{2}\log n + \frac{\gamma+\log 2}{2} + o(1), $$ where the constant part has value $0.63518142\cdots$.

Comment: Euler had the correct solution in mind, and the citation of him was wrong. And from this also the use of this formula to indicate Euler's fallability (one might use another case, but this case hasn't been a case of error) See my answer and my last comment to the OP's question. (Meanwhile I had mail-exchange with the author)

Answer (score 5):

That is quite strange... since even it is understood as a precursory notation for asymptotic expansion, still we should get

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{2k+1} = \frac{1}{2}\log n + C + \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{11}{48n^{2}} + \cdots, $$

where

$$ C = \frac{\gamma}{2} + \log 2 \approx 0.98175501301071173972. $$

Answer (score 5):

This expression is wrong and it is used to prove a point. Here is the first sentence in the paragraph above the expression.

> The observation is that Euler was far from infallible.

The author is saying that even Euler makes mistakes.

---

Picture of page:

[image]

Comment: The author goes on to state that *some* meaning can be found by the expressions. Namely that both sides of the first equation are infinite and that the second equation is correct when stated as a limit in the obvious way.

Comment: *fall = far (typo that I'm not allowed to correct).

Comment: Quite funny... you forgot to scan the bottom of the page. The $3$ is actually the footnote number for reference, as the $4$ in the second formula.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly relevant:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}1+\frac13+\frac15+\dotsb+\frac1n-\frac12\ln(n)\approx0.63518$$

The number's off, though…

[Here's the full page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wQtT.jpg) from the book. Can anyone follow the footnote?

Comment: please see one reference into Euler's original work in my new answer *(Of course, having one reference it does not mean, that possibly Euler might have computed that value various times in various articles and one time erred with the computation/with the print. Don't have the source from the book which the OP refers to)*

Comment: I should mention that the constant is $\dfrac{\gamma+\ln2}2$. This follows from $\lim_{n\to\infty}1+\frac12+\frac13+\dotsb+\frac1n-\ln n=\gamma$ and from $1-\frac12+\frac13-\dotsb=\ln2$.

Answer (score 1):

After a little research in the Euler-book to which the author of "Euler: The master of us all" refers, it seems that the alleged wrong equation does not occur at all in Euler's book.
This is likely
a) because of failing textsearch for the number $0.66215$ as well as for $66215$ (other numbers and/or text *can* be found) and
b) because it does not seem that the book deals with that deeper number-theoretical problems at all.
Here is a searchable book-preview using google: [the Hewlett-translation](http://books.google.de/books?hl=de&id=X8yv0sj4_1YC&q=66215#v=onepage&q=330&f=false)

So, the example of the author W. Dunham for the fallibility of L. Euler seems to be an unfounded, at least an unlucky one. In the contrary, the derivation of the formula actually occurs (for instance) in the english translation (Jordan Bell) of E47 ("Eneström-index") kept on [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.4096v1)  and it contains also the correct value $= 0.6351814227307392$ . This occurs in item (30) on page 10 of the pdf-file.

Here is a picture of the scan of the [original E047 at the Euler-archives](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E047.html) (I've marked the number by a red box):
[image: picture]

*Remark: Of course, having one reference does not mean that possibly Euler might have computed that value various times in various articles and one time erred with the computation/with the print. But it seems that it does not exist at all in the book, where the OP's literature points to*